# React Native: null is not an object (evaluating 'NativeMusicControl.STATE_PLAYING')

Tags: react-native

I create new project in react native expo cli. Install react-native-music-control and add only import to App.js:

[App.js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4QCk.png)

I have error on the mobile:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNpp0.jpg)

I have equal problems with other music control library.
What i can do with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this package in expo it seems since you need to configure native segments on both iOS and Android.
Create a new React Native project without expo.

For iOS in the terminal you should execute in the terminal `pod install --project-directory=ios/`

For Android in the AndroidManifest.xml add

```
<uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

and

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

This is per documentation of the package :
https://github.com/tanguyantoine/react-native-music-control#ios